# fillna() method's behavior in Pandas -- does not obey to inplace argument - returns error on axis 1

Tags: python, nan

I am experimenting with the fillna() method.  I have created a small dataframe and two Series for that purpose:

```
        col1    col2    col3      col4
     0  NaN      NaN    3           4
     1  NaN      NaN    7           8
     2  9.0     10.0    11         12

     n1 = pd.Series([10, 20])
     n2 = pd.Series([30, 40, 50, 60])
     n2.index = list(df.columns.values)
```

When I try the command:

```
    df.fillna(n1, axis=0, inplace = True)
```

Nothing happens, the NaNs remain intact.  I would expect to see them replaced with the values 10 (col1) and 20 (col2).
When I try

```
    df.fillna(n2, axis =1)
```

I get an error message:

```
   NotImplementedError: Currently only can fill with dict/Series column by column
```

Could you explain this behavior?  Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried the inplace argument and still is not working.  Moreover, the replace method returns an error when called with axis=1.  Therefore, it is not a duplicate of the question you indicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fillna` (like many other methods in pandas) isn't inplace by default. You need to either pass `inplace=True` or reassign its return value.

```
df.fillna(n1, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

or

```
df = df.fillna(n1, axis=0)
```

In such cases it helps to read the docs:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

> **inplace** : boolean, default False.
>   If True, fill in place. Note: this will modify any other views on this object, (e.g. a no-copy slice for a column in a DataFrame)
>   .
>   .
>   **Returns**: filled : DataFrame